# Facebook Graph API for iphone passing access token

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Graph API like this example [API](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API)

It is verifying login credentials in View did Appear and calling all the method in one view. I want to use these methods in other views but how to pass access token to other views(maintains login session). Here is code for login

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    //Facebook Application ID

    NSString *client_id = @"142759389130183";

    //alloc and initalize our FbGraph instance
    self.fbGraph = [[FbGraph alloc] initWithFbClientID:client_id];

    //begin the authentication process.....
    //[fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:) 
    //                   andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins"];



        [fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:) andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access" andSuperView:self.view];


}
- (void)fbGraphCallback:(id)sender {

    if ( (fbGraph.accessToken == nil) || ([fbGraph.accessToken length] == 0) ) {

        NSLog(@"You pressed the 'cancel' or 'Dont Allow' button, you are NOT logged into Facebook...I require you to be logged in & approve access before you can do anything useful....");

        //restart the authentication process.....
    //  [fbGraph authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:self andSelector:@selector(fbGraphCallback:) 
            //               andExtendedPermissions:@"user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream,offline_access,user_checkins,friends_checkins"];

    //  StartPage *startPage = [[StartPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"StartPage" bundle:nil];
        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:startPage animated:YES];



        //[startPage release];

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        //pop a message letting them know most of the info will be dumped in the log
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" message:@"You are logged into facebook" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        NSLog(@"------------>CONGRATULATIONS<------------, You're logged into Facebook...  Your oAuth token is:  %@", fbGraph.accessToken);



    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain clearly about ur problem..

Comment: call these method from other views..you can always do that :)

Comment: I want to create different view for home, profile, photo upload and when I logged in then  navigate to another view , I want to post photo in album of logged in user. how could I know about logged in user, all these methods are working in one view.

Comment: @zoozoo Only logout method is called from other view..getmefeedbuttonpressed method is returning null value

Comment: no it cannot return null...do one thing...get all the values you want to show in one array in view 1 and show that array on other view's tableview .

Comment: I have done with that which u told me earlier.Now I want to post image from other view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 -(IBAction)postMeFeedButtonPressed:(id)sender {

postFeedCustom *detailViewController = [[postFeedCustom alloc] initWithNibName:@"postFeedCustom" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

}

```
-(void)postMeFeedCustomized{
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];

[variables setObject:postString forKey:@"message"];
//[variables setObject:@"http://bit.ly/bFTnqd" forKey:@"link"];
//[variables setObject:@"This is the bolded copy next to the image" forKey:@"name"];
//[variables setObject:@"This is the plain text copy next to the image.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy." forKey:@"description"];

FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/feed" withPostVars:variables];
NSLog(@"postMeFeedButtonPressed:  %@", fb_graph_response.htmlResponse);

//parse our json
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
NSDictionary *facebook_response = [parser objectWithString:fb_graph_response.htmlResponse error:nil];   
[parser release];

//let's save the 'id' Facebook gives us so we can delete it if the user presses the 'delete /me/feed button'

self.feedPostId = (NSString *)[facebook_response objectForKey:@"id"];
NSLog(@"feedPostId, %@", feedPostId);
NSLog(@"Now log into Facebook and look at your profile...");
```

}

in another class where you want user to post his custom message...
you can do like this..

```
  -(void) viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
appDelegate=(oAuth2TestAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

}

```
 -(IBAction)FeedPost:(id)sender{
postString=postField.text;
[appDelegate.viewController postMeFeedCustomized];
postField.text=@"";
[postField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

have you seen that?? in this method for the button I have called the `postfeedcustomized` method and I am storing the textfield parameter in the `postString` and this is that postStirng that I am posting in `postfeedcustomized` method. see this instruction `[variables setObject:postString forKey:@"message"];`

here post string is the string ...which is in viewController 2 ...it carries the message entered by the user..now This is the code for posting message from another view...when button is pressed for posting feed it will go to another view controller where is a textbox..there user enters his message...and after he enters message the method `postfeedcustomized` is being called from that viewController..I have done this for the status only...chage it according to u r need and post pic from another View..

Comment: Ok I will try this .You mean Postmefeedcustomize method should be written in other view from where I have to send message?

Comment: no it is on the same class but it should get called from other viewcontroller. when you press button or something you want to do...in another class

Comment: yup tell me what happend?? you did that??

Comment: yaa. I can call it from other view. But How could I pass parameters means I want to make it dynamic. suppose I have to send message from textfield then how to pass this in method.should I create new method with parameter

Comment: okay...you suppose to create a new view with parameter and then you have to call post feed custom from that class...wait i am editing the answer after some time..

Comment: This is ok. but if I call postPicture method (which is hardcoded ) is called from other class but returning null.And if i call with in same class it is returning posted id..

Comment: something is missing..because all other methods are called properly but this facebook method is not called..-(void)postmefeed is also returning null for hardcoded value.

Comment: what??? do you want to say that`[postField resignFirstResponder];` is not being called?? am i getting right?? what is happening is it giving any error??

Comment: I mean If I hardcoded the value of message in postmefeed method and call it from other class . This method is called but not posting that hardcoded message..Returning null on console

Comment: check it again because I am getting here posted the message written by user.

Comment: Ya i am also getting hardcoded and user written messages ..But when I am trying call this method somewhere else it is returning null.

Comment: If i create object of oauthtestview then call [oauth postmefeed] then it will call this method but result is null

Answer (score 0):

I use Facebook API too. In my code I've a "FacebookLogger" who is a singleton with a Facebook object.

To store session I use NSUserDefaults [(find docs here)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:m_Facebook.accessToken forKey:@"AccessToken"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:m_Facebook.expirationDate forKey:@"ExpirationDate"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Where m_Facebook is my Facebook object in my singleton.
After that I can catch Access with :

```
m_Facebook.accessToken    = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"AccessToken"];

m_Facebook.expirationDate = (NSDate *) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ExpirationDate"];
```

Comment: How can pass this Access-token and Expiration-date for Login in iOS ?